# Invoke external jar file from POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a jar file and I invoke the jar using

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I want to invoke the myjar.jar from my project. How can i invoke the same form POM file of my project?

Comment: More info needed. Why and when do you need the jar to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to do such thing just take a deep look into [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) which support exactly such things.